# GnuPG/OpenPGP in the corporate world

Tags: gnupg

Is GnuPG/OpenPGP a good solution to protect internal company email communication?

With PRISM and previous major company hacking news stories, I'm looking for a solid way to protect company confidential information while communicating by email?

Another concern is that most people are often need to access their email while on the move. It seems that Android does not yet have any solid support for GPG/PGP encryption through official apps.

Is GnuPG/OpenPGP more of a hassle than a benefit in a corporate environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "hassle" is a trade off depending on what you are trying to protect. But it is benefficial to use GPG/PGP if you want to protect your emails. Make sure to train your employees.

On a side note:

[image: xkcd - Security]

If they really would want to get access to your files I don't think the NSA would be discouraged because you are using PGP, if the file is encrypted they will get the key...somehow.

<sub><sup>image via [xkcd.com](http://xkcd.com/538/)</sup></sub>

Comment: Nice pic xD. Actually that's true

Comment: It's notable that [rubber hose cryptanalysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber-hose_cryptanalysis) is hard to keep secret, so at least you'd *know* that they're spying on you.